# HazelCast in spring boot application is throwing the error that You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast

2019-01-09 09:29:04.290  WARN [api-gateway-server,,,] 1 --- [cached.thread-3] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastService      : [10.255.7.232]:5701 [dev] [3.8.9] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!

java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted

```
at java.base/java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method) ~[na:na]


at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:695) ~[na:na]


at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:252) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.searchForOtherClusters(MulticastJoiner.java:112) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.SplitBrainHandler.searchForOtherClusters(SplitBrainHandler.java:75) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.SplitBrainHandler.run(SplitBrainHandler.java:42) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.executionservice.impl.DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator$DelegateDecorator.run(DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator.java:66) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:227) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]


at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]


at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]


at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]
```

2019-01-09 09:29:06.949  WARN [api-gateway-server,,,] 1 --- [cached.thread-5] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastService      : [10.255.7.232]:5702 [dev] [3.8.9] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!

java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted

```
at java.base/java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method) ~[na:na]


at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:695) ~[na:na]


at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:252) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.searchForOtherClusters(MulticastJoiner.java:112) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.SplitBrainHandler.searchForOtherClusters(SplitBrainHandler.java:75) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.SplitBrainHandler.run(SplitBrainHandler.java:42) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.executionservice.impl.DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator$DelegateDecorator.run(DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator.java:66) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:227) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]


at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]


at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]


at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]
```

2019-01-09 09:29:09.387  WARN [api-gateway-server,,,] 1 --- [cached.thread-1] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastService      : [10.255.7.232]:5703 [dev] [3.8.9] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!

java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted

```
at java.base/java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method) ~[na:na]


at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:695) ~[na:na]


at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:252) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.searchForOtherClusters(MulticastJoiner.java:112) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.SplitBrainHandler.searchForOtherClusters(SplitBrainHandler.java:75) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.SplitBrainHandler.run(SplitBrainHandler.java:42) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.executionservice.impl.DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator$DelegateDecorator.run(DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator.java:66) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:227) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]


at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]


at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]


at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]


at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80) ~[hazelcast-3.8.9.jar!/:3.8.9]
```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace and your hazelcast configuration?

Comment: Above I have mentioned the stacktrace

Comment: I have added the configuration and stacktrace as well

Answer (score 1):

Exception message `You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!` is misleading. It's already fixed in upcoming version 3.12. See Github PR [Fix exception message when multicast send fails](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/13960).

Actual failure is multicast send is not permitted by the underlying OS. And that's mostly caused by sending multicast datagrams in parallel. This may happen when you start multiple Hazelcast members concurrently on the same host.

For more info;

- https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/7198#issuecomment-430143211
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.protocols.tcp-ip/Qou9Sfgr77E/mVQAPaeI-VUJ

Comment: I am using 3 beans to create the cache inside the hazelcast configuration. So how shall I insure I dont face the same error again?

Comment: Are you creating 3 caches inside a single Hazelcast instance or 3 Hazelcast instances for each cache?

Comment: 3 Hazelcast instances for 3 caches.

Comment: Is it something related to the TCP socket? Because in my local its working fine but in SIT environment its throwing this error while connecting to 3 diffrent ports.

Comment: No, this is related to multicast UDP socket, which is used by Hazelcast's multicast discovery. I suggest you to use TCP-IP discovery instead of multicast. See [Hazelcast discovery mechanisms](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#discovery-mechanisms)

Comment: Same here. I am running embedded hazelcast in each micro service. But, I am facing it in version 3.12.7 .  In my case when in morning system starts, all the services starts at same time on ec2 VM . What should be done in this scenario?. My hazelcast config is simplest, just giving cluster name & eviction policy. That's it